# A question about moment maps

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, group-actions

The following is from page 3 of  the article Matsuki correspondence for sheaves:

> Let $G$ be a semi-simple Lie group with a maximal compact subgroup $K$. Let $\mathfrak{g}= \mathfrak{k} \oplus \mathfrak{s} $ be the corresponding Cartan decomposition. Let $V$ be a finite dimensional representation of $G$ over $\mathbb{R}$. We denote by $P(V)$ the projective space associated to $V$.
> There exists a $K$-invariant inner product $(,)$ on $V$ such that any $\alpha \in \mathfrak{s} $ acts as a symmetric operator. A choice of such inner product gives a moment map
> $m_V: P(V) \rightarrow \mathfrak{s}^*$ by the formula
> $$<m_V(v),\alpha>= \frac{(\alpha v,v)}{(v,v)}, \alpha \in \mathfrak{s}.$$

My question is why is this moment map defined from $P(V)$ to $\mathfrak{s}^*$ not to $\mathfrak{g}^*$, because I know that in general if $G$ is a Lie group acting on a manifold $M$, where the action is Hamiltonian, then by definition the moment map has values in $\mathfrak{g}^*$?

Comment: Well since $\alpha \in \mathfrak{s}$ in the formula, the resulting map is in $\mathfrak{s}^*$. Have you checked what happens if you try to put a general $\alpha \in \mathfrak{g}$ into the formula?

Comment: I Know that since the inner product on $V$  is $K$-invariant, then if $\alpha \in \mathfrak{k}$,  we get $(\alpha v, v) =-(v,\alpha v)$, but I don't know How to use this ! could you give me some hints please ?

Comment: I really don't know either. I would have guessed that for $\alpha \in \mathfrak{k}$ the map is trivial so we could naturally restrict to $\mathfrak{s}$, but I actually doubt that now. Maybe they are just wanting to focus on $\mathfrak{s}^*$ instead of $\mathfrak{g}^*$.

Comment: Since we have a decomposition $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{k} \oplus \mathfrak{s}$ we can identify (if we want) $\mathfrak{s}^*$ with the annihilator of $\mathfrak{k}$ which is a subspace of $\mathfrak{g}^*$. We could of course do the same for $\mathfrak{k}^*$ and get a decomposition of $\mathfrak{g}^*$. Moreover since the original decomposition is orthogonal for the Killing form this one will be for the dual of the Killing form

Comment: That's not to say that's what the author is doing. They might just want to call this object a moment map because it is similar to the normal one.